# Insertion sort using python (what is the issue here, i`m not getting any error but this program won`t run)

Tags: python, loops, insertion-sort

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value=list[index]
        i=index-1
        while i>=0:
            if value<list[1]:
                list[i+1]=list[i]  # shift no in slot i to i+1
                list[i]=value   # shift value left into slot i
                i=i-1
            else:
                break
k =input("enter no of elements")
print(insertion_sort(k))
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything so I'm not sure what you expected to be printed.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot return statement you are controlling wrong index in if statement.

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value=list[index]
        i=index-1
        while i>=0:
            if value<list[i]: # careful on here
                list[i+1]=list[i]  # shift no in slot i to i+1
                list[i]=value   # shift value left into slot i
                i=i-1
            else:
                break
    return list

values = raw_input("enter values:") # 6 2 4 7 2 1 8
values = [ int(x) for x in values.split(' ') ] # then use this values array in insertion_sort function
print(insertion_sort(values))
```

That will print 1,2,2,4,6,7,8

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I am able to run this way. But I want to enter array as an input and not hard code it. How can I do that ?

Comment: def insertion_sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value=list[index]
        i=index-1
        while i>=0:
            if value<list[i]:
                list[i+1]=list[i]  # shift no in slot i to i+1
                list[i]=value   # shift value left into slot i
                i=i-1
            else:
                break
    return(list)

arr = []
elem = int(input("insert how many elements you want:"))
for i in range(0, elem):
    arr.append(int(input("Enter next no :")))
print (arr)
print(insertion_sort(arr))      GUILTY taking internet help for input!!

Comment: You can get values with raw_input as string seperating each number with one blank char and with list comprehensions convert them to int array.

Comment: values = raw_input("enter values:") # 6 2 4 7 2 1 8
values = [ int(x) for x in values.split(' ') ] # then use this values array in insertion_sort function.. I've updated my code.

Comment: Is it OK if I referred internet to find the part where I need to input the array. Should I be guilty ? :D  :(

Comment: I updated the input part. Isn't it ok? It works well.

Comment: your program gives the error   "NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined" So you have to use    arr = [] elem = int(input("insert how many elements you want:")) for i in range(0, elem): arr.append(int(input("Enter next no :")))

Comment: Ok i see now. If you are using Python 3.x you have to use input(), you can use raw_input in Python 2.x. That is the problem:)